# Does $ObjMapi work the way that I think it does?

Tags: flowtype

I cannot get the `$ObjMapi<>` [utility type](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/utilities/#toc-objmapi) to behave how I would expect.

Given some type like so:

```
type TheActionMap = {|
  A: {| type: 'A', payload: number |},
  B: {| type: 'B', payload: string |},
  C: {| type: 'C' |},
|};
```

This has the redundancy of the key being part of the value. In order to simplify this code, and to help enforce this rule, I'd prefer to instead define it like so:

```
type SimpleActionMap = {|
  A: {| payload: number |},
  B: {| payload: string |},
  C: {||},
|}

// Maps the type so that the Key is added into the value as the `type` property
export type ExpandedActions<A> = $Exact<$ObjMapi<
  A,
  <K, V>(K, V) => {| ...V, type: K |},
>>;

type TheActionMap2 = ExpandedActions<SimpleActionMap>
```

Unfortunately, in my testing, these two types *do not* behave the same. While the former works as I'd expect in all cases, the latter misses some obvious type errors like:

```
({
  A: { type: 'A', payload: 'bad' },
  B: { type: 'B', payload: 'foo' },
  C: { type: 'C' },
}: TheActionMap2);
```

Which gives no type error at all. What am I missing here? Do I not understand how `$ObjMapi` is intended to work, or are there bugs in the flow implementation?

Shockingly, I also discovered that usage of `ExpandedActions<SimpleActionMap>` and `TheActionMap2` (where the latter is an alias for the former) **have different behavior in the same scenarios**. This is very likely a bug, which I've [submitted on github](https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/8508).

[Here is a complete try flow example with all of my test cases](https://flow.org/try/#0PQKhCgAJIZQSwLYAcA2BTSB3A9gJwNZwB2A5pGgB4CGy6kAZnLgM4AuANFgBZq4YJUkkAG5UUAVwxi+VACYBPSAGNsRVlWLNIrHpHxp5AOiiQAUuLaQLxMgBIAamMlbMcHdq5wXefFqpbKJDQlVjRZKBBgcHBWeSDIABUeAEEQuFUAWUFIAF5IAG8AHxNkgC4Cwu04tHKAcmTaziQqeRRsOXKicQQAI15IQoBfdhMAIXKiqqC60cbIZtb22XK2XBsB4ZMAYQnK2OnIWq3ajZGhgG5o-YxU1nSiLTyHJzRmAB4ktFv7rKQAPmiAAp8lMaocGk0Wm0OpAAOyQQblb6qZgASkuwNBMzmC2hy0O9Gw2BOiMgyIe6PAmOudWOCKRaRRlOAwEgtgAYm1MABRChBEJhbm4XB4KkgmngnFQpZ1HpyEkMu5My4stmc7A8vnBUKyIUi3BirGHWaQxYwgAM9LJjIpKtZHK5vP5Or1oup1VpUrN+NqhOJVvJaLtasdWoFuuFbvypMDzPt6s1zsFkYN7oOtQAIgrrUrbeBVQ6NU7tcn9YaJfVs7Hg4XEyWI2XMbiZQSiVWbUH8-HQ0mG1H5tKYfCYx3KV3IABaKfTmezufzheL6eQFnRUAQaAASSIHgwsleTDCymw+84On42Vk2FekCI2FYkD4snERFkVDUKEU+8YRAw59BkDvrIu56AYxhbg8oRyJwtgAPI9AAVr8cCQF4VjMEerDYMeyDiKEIH7swh7AdcDAiggIFEbQ-Skd+xBuPcERRDE1SwIgqBfDavy5BUJS7AO3qdN0fS4KcYz8c2MKrOsQwjNAOwVLJ4BDGurK-Fo-6kcw2E6FQD7-gA0gYqF+LI+7AcQWEgaIEhSBpugAAbXA58wikEuCxOAgR4PprFOkBYSBm8yR-Dxti8lQIRvHBiHIW8JRyZAbwGZw9h-ICKWQPYqK5KFkyGAV9hnh6kAGWJfx-Jc46fJAJDtCgkDYPQHhof5r6BR2AFobpD5uFgcAoA1Yhcuh2jYSQaC-rgel-roaAAI7iHANmTb58T0ORkBURxokqPu1VzWG6i5iZHh6eObXmUF8DUeSvyhTkj2JCkXGCOOox4SBfQjcwXAavZem7l+2F3g+fRcFQwizRgzA0GgLHxJ8d2CAATDxl0dbm7w3RxyP-FVqo1RDSBIIoSj+DebTYPgjX4OAKiQdorysPBCE8fkfEFEalamni5TDol4xcxWJoCXzrb+ps8kTNzdKbIMGKhGwrPlEjr1IJSgJKyziGqy9ua-CjY6quyGgoBp2Hk6wShcIBAEIF4AjW1w9MovpzOs6Mcjs5z4olTzYstrUcqyCSgsyyLXri76bYIolCl++mcsjAr461sW4auqm2uezCasG4IcYhkWR2lm6OeIV7+L5z8qNF+npd9tnHuVzCGOyNd7HoHjfzG6yOPoKJ2sAw+CEWA+hJKBYjU7v+NnOGR2AUf+AhIAjNwdmjTyOLZ7zt53t3qxVVVpmCAeSfiw6KvczBGxiidn6LF91H67ZY3f5b+3L18oh-BYJhnF0KZJxbT+uIFAwF6Bm0gM+P82FiA2TgMBC+n90wQkDjCYO8oAyb3rgAxuWcQG-WwOAyB0DYFjVQkQRByDBzhFPtiXmLZLQjnfngns9Ys6oLPscJhmDX44LYTWfBvZCETlASQiBDByGSEoQ7ZgRFSCgjFKwm+f9uwl1ESmbhdQsyCLUewzRnDgHiOIaQ6RA0YGyKsvIxRZAUEMMlPo3+hi6yZxMRI8xUDLF9HJhYP8rE0K2JsJwHon1NBQTIQNLQFCrKYBFEoi+yimx0JfrHVRLjhEcPcfqIhYCpHeIar4qg-iupaGCaQUJ4TIJoG9oUmJ1jsLxNUPYuhySQTPzhM4h4H81xgBMDAP6ShCCkE-JwawSiqAATEHAfwygIakBvP+cGkN0gGkgJEVSsA4aAS0IGFGVSHz+L8NMlAszmDrxzDfAAzGFHezgPj61rkgFGlUgQPzqOgzpV8rkomuZrD5xoo5BwERkh4-z76yzfjc1xgCy6iVMfkqJDVYnwOoTM2h3odGSj4T6EO0K-mwoIR4sxBSZFwKoTQjB9DAW1CfqkyALCf7gqJVoxstLeHUrSZLZlzAIVpxEcY3JiLJHIqsRSipZBrgqN5fy-+2SgHsu5nosFfLWVCrwHk0VFiUWNMgJK6l2LKzdLVVkoxOTNUiq8dA4ppTSJBK8HYw5VC2C1ORQ0ilzTEltOlSkwSEsCUsrNW4xVlrPFkp8cEEpGEyn6sdSEyAYTeo1LqWbD1lCvWtO9O0rlXTVUQqAA)